# Rails - What's the proper way to use scopes to check if a record exists for the current day only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In our website we will have a search history feature so users can view and retrieve their last x number of searches for the current day.

I would like to check that the user hasn't already entered the same keyword for **the current day** before creating a new record. These records would be kept in the db for a few days before being removed so if I just validate the uniqueness of the keyword and the user entered that keyword in the past, the record would not be created.

Below is how I have my model and controller setup. Bear with me, I'm still learning about rails and scopes.

**MODEL**

```
class UserLog < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :query_type, presence: true
   validates :keyword, presence: true
   validates :url, presence: true

   validates_uniqueness_of :id

   scope :user_searches, -> (user = nil) {where(user_id: user).order(created_at: :desc)}
   scope :today_only, -> {where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)}

end
```

**I believe I could add these checks in my model that would do what I want.**

```
validates_uniqueness_of :keyword, scope: :keyword, conditions: -> {where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)}

OR THIS?

validates_uniqueness_of :keyword, conditions: -> {where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)}
```

**And the controller**

```
# to save user query in db
if query_valid (other checks in controller)  
  UserLog.create(user_id: current_user.id, query_type: query_type, keyword: query_value, url: request.fullpath)
end
```

**And to get records to display on user request**

```
@recent_searches = UserLog.user_searches(current_user).today_only.limit(15)
```

Comment: Do you want it to fail? (validation error) or simply don't store it?

Comment: I simply dont want to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day` sounds overcomplicated to me. How about you store `created_on` just like `created_at`, but a Date, not a DateTime. Your uniqueness scope becomes much easier, similarly creation could be:

```
current_user.logs.where(keyword: query_value, created_on: Date.today).first_or_create(other_fields)
```

I'm assuming user `has_many :logs`, for readability. Instead of `UserLog.create(user_id: current_user.id, ...`

Comment: Thanks Leito. That's a good idea. I appreciate the help. You are correct a user does have many logs.

Comment: One last question. In your example what is `.first_or_create(other_fields` for? Can I do that to both check and create the record within the model instead of this  code `UserLog.create(user_id: current_user.id, query_type: query_type, keyword: query_value, url: request.fullpath)` in the controller?

Comment: Well, the arguments on the first where, both compare (to find a matching record) or sets those fields for the new record if not found. The fields you pass to `first_or_create` aren't use for the comparison, but if a record is not found those are set too.

In your case, you where comparing keyboard and created_on for uniqueness, if you don't find one, you can set query_type and url.

Comment: Thanks. There are so many new things I'm discovering about rails. I did not know about first_or_create. So I can instead do:

`current_user.logs.where(keyword: query_value, created_on: Date.today).first_or_create(query_type: query_type, keyword: query_value, url: request.fullpath)`

Comment: Yes, glad to help and welcome to the Rails world! I'm learning every day too, you should check the guides for the latest syntax sugar: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object